# Java 9 Eclipse 4.7 Portable export error "resource not found", "Could not find main method from given launch configuration."

Tags: java, android, eclipse, maven, java-9

A few days ago I installed Oracle JDK 9. I tried to use Eclipse, but it didn't work. I looked around and found [this](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/java-9-support-beta-oxygen/login-warning) link. So I updated my Eclipse with the link showed after

> To try out Java 9 support in Eclipse, you can follow any of these:

by clicking on Help -> Install New Software... and then inserting the link. This went fine and I already could started coding and I could also run it.

But I didn't manage to do the second step, because dragging the Install button did nothing.

(Second step:)

> Update your Eclipse 4.7 build for committers using Eclipse Marketplace entry (currently, needs some additional steps):

Then I realised that I didn't have the Eclipse Marketplace Client, so I installed it and then it went fine.

But here is the problem:
When I try to Export it as a runnable jar file I get this error: "JAR creation failed. See details for additional information.
  No resources selected
  Jar export finished with problems. See details for additional information.
    Could not find main method from given launch configuration.
"

[image: Error Message in Eclipse]

I already tried creating new Launch Configurations, Making a completly new empty project, and creating a new workspace. Nothing did work.

Has anyone an Idea why this doesn't work and what I can do to fix this?

EDIT

My eclipse.ini:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.4.0.v20161219-1356.jar
--launcher.library
  plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.500.v20170921-1704
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vm
C:/Program Files/Java/jdk-9/bin/javaw.exe   
-vmargs
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
```

Comment: @nullpointer No, I did configure my eclipse.ini and I have already eclipse 4.7.1a and have already choosen Java 9 as default. I can just not export my procets.

Comment: Did you try to create a jar of your project from the command line? Was that successful?

Comment: I did never do it before, now I tried it with a new project that just prints something and compiled it with the command promt (compiling, creating manifest and creating jar), and that worked. But I have no Clue how I can do this with many packages and libraries

Comment: EDIT: Tried it out a bit more and got it to work, but thats extremly tedious. Do you have any Idea how I can get eclipse to work?

Comment: @abilnf, do you care to share the extra steps which you call "extremely tedious"? With that info we can search [bugzilla](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/query.cgi) (select Eclipse / JDT / Debug) to see if there's already a matching RFE to simplify the workflow.

Comment: @StephanHerrmann I don't know if you got me wrong, but with "extremely tedious" i didn't mean eclipse but rather creating a jar withhout eclipse. And if you didn't get me wrong: maybe it's not "extremely tedious", but it's a lot easier to just say "export as runnable jar" than copying all classes, all libraries, put all classes and libraries in the classpath and making a jar out of it. And that for every time I wan't to try it out (and that is a lot)

Comment: I can reproduce in Eclipse Oxygen.1a (yet unreleased), so I filed https://bugs.eclipse.org/525711

Comment: @StephanHerrmann thanky you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As also confirmed in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46475709/java-9-eclipse-4-7-portable-export-error-resource-not-found-could-not-find-m/47379471#comment80190963_46475709), the issue is filed as **[BUG#525711](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=525711)** in Eclipse.

***Update***:- It has been verified as fixed in *M20171115-1700*, which primarily means that if one is using nightly or builds released after November 15, 2017 they should be able to create JAR using Eclipse.

=> Though another point to note here shall be that this causes a subsequent **[BUG#527114](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=527114)** for failure in handling multiple modules while creating the JAR.

I would guess one shall mostly expect these updated in the [Eclipse Photon build](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.8/M3/) in future.

Comment: I have the same problem with `Build id: 20171218-0600`

Answer (score 0):

I have `Build id: 20171218-0600` and the problem is still (or again) in there.

The original bug (525711) has been reopened as (526037):

> https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=526037