# Eclipse Java9 Export Runnable JAR file

Tags: java, eclipse, java-9

I am trying to setup Eclipse with Java 9 but the Export -> Runnable JAR file is not working since it can't find the main method.

Context:

- Windows 10
- Eclipse IDE version Oxygen 1a Release (4.7.1a) Build: 20171005-1200
- JDK 9.0.1 and JRE 9.0.1 installed & setup in Eclipse

What I did:

- File -> New Java Project

[image: Create New Java Project]

- Click on "Finish"

---

- Right click on src -> New -> Class
  [image: Add new class]

---

Edited Main.java to following code:

```
package com.application;

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.version"));
  }
}
```

Run -> No errors.

Console log result: "9.0.1"

---

Now I want to export the code to a Runnable JAR:
Right click on the Project -> Export -> Runnable JAR file

[image: Error message]

So I went to the Run Configurations but the Main class is defined:

[image: Main class is defined in the run configurations]

---

With Java 8 there was no problem exporting the jar following the steps above.

What do I have to do, to use the "export to Runnable JAR file" in Java 9?

Comment: Mostly you are facing the ***[BUG#525711](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=525711)*** and this shall be closed and tracked under [Java 9 Eclipse 4.7 Portable export error “resource not found”, “Could not find main method from given launch configuration.”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46475709/java-9-eclipse-4-7-portable-export-error-resource-not-found-could-not-find-m). Though that still doesn't have an answer and hence unable to mark this as duplicate.

Comment: Have the exact same problem. IDE is pretty useless if I can't export my code to a usable format by other people...

Comment: >  IDE is pretty useless. 
Unfortunately this is still true almost a year later... :-( Guess, it's time to switch...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same problem and I used the export "Jar file" option, not the "Runnable Jar file".
[image: jar file option]
Then I selected the options as shown below.
[image: options1]
[image: options2]
At the final step I selected a main class to make my jar runnable.
[image: final configuration]
By clicking "Browse" you get the available main classes.